# Arrancar servicio al iniciar dispositivo android 10

Tags: java, android, servicio, background

Estoy intentando arrancar un servicio cuando se reinicia o apaga y enciende el móvil y las soluciones que he visto solo funcionan con versiones de android antiguas, tengo una app que es un chat y su servicio en segundo plano, cuando reinicio el móvil necesitas entrar de nuevo a la app para que se arranque el servicio, necesito arrancarlo al inicio.

He probado con este permiso en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

y con un broadcastReceiver y en android 10 no me funciona.

Gracias.

Comment: No sirve o el proceso que trata de realizar es el que no sirve, has visto el LogCat?

Comment: Sii, en versiones inferiores a android 10 si funciona, al reiniciar se abre la aplicación, pero en android 10 nada... He puesto un log y no lo muestra.

Comment: Mi pregunta se refiere a que proceso realiza cuando se inicia el dispositivo?

Comment: El BroadcastReceiver abre un activity

Comment: Pues debería funcionar... comprueba que el broadcast está bien registrado en el manifest, con el intent filter  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> y que está entrando en el onReceive, para ésto puedes lanzar una notificación y verificarlo.

Comment: quizá esto te sirva https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1

Comment: Os dejo el mismo problema subido con más información https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690897/open-android-service-or-activity-on-boot-api-29   está igual que en la página y nada, en versiones recientes de android no funciona.

Answer (score -1):

No sé si llego tarde, pero por si acaso, a partir de **SDK 28 (Android 9)** hay que incluir en el *Manifiesto*:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
```

Para que funcionen los servicios y se arranquen.

Por otro lado, dependiendo del móvil que tengas también es posible que tengas que dar la autorización de inicio automático. Yo tengo un *Xiaomi Redmi 8 pro* y la aplicación, por ejemplo, del reloj no se ejecutaba hasta que entraba en ella. Una vez puesto este permiso al encenderse el móvil, ya se ejecuta sola.

Espero haberte ayudado